# Graph of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I would like to know the definition of a graph of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is a set.

Each time, I found links about graph theory but here is my context:

[image: pb def: U subset of R^n]

[image: Gr U]

Comment: Did you mean the graph of a function?

Comment: $U$ is not a function but a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
When they write $Gr\, U$ they mean in fact $Gr \, u$ ?

Comment: I think what they mean is the graph of $f_{|_U}$.